# How to call a .exe file from a .bat file from within a 'if' condition?

Tags: batch-file

I need to launch a .exe file based on an environment variable from a .bat file. My batch file reads as follows:

```
@echo off 
if %MY_ENV%==1 (
call "HelloWorld.exe" ) else (
echo FAIL! )
```

Both batch file and the executable are in the same directory. But I am not able to launch the exe. Please help!

Comment: What error message are you getting? (edit it into your post)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off 
if %MY_ENV%==1 (
"HelloWorld.exe" ) else (
echo FAIL! )
```

You were using "call" unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, it is unnecessary but it can be used.

Comment: I'd use `if "%MY_ENV%"=="1"` to avoid trouble with empty variable or some special characters...